# character array to floating point conversion

Tags: c, unix, type-conversion

I am trying to convert the output buffer(character array)
of the code below to floating point format for further calculations.
Can anybody tell me how to do it.

```
#include "usbtmc.h"
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int main() 
{

    int myfile;
    char buffer[4000];

    int actual;

    myfile=open("/dev/usbtmc1",O_RDWR);
    if(myfile>0)
    {
        system("echo MEAS:VOLT:AC?>/dev/usbtmc1");
        actual=read(myfile,buffer,4000);

        buffer[actual] = 0;
        printf("Response = \n %s\n",buffer);

        close(myfile);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

The sample output for this code is

**Response = 
 +1.29273072E-04**

Comment: can't you use atof? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atof/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may have two ways:

1. using [double `atof`(const char* str)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atof/)

   ```
   float f;
   f = (float)atof(buffer);
   printf("%f",f); // here you can use f
   ```
2. using [int `sscanf`( const char * s, const char * format, ...)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/?kw=sscanf)

   ```
   float f;
   sscanf(buffer,"%f",&f);
   printf("%f",f); // here you can use f
   ```