# Converting binary to floating point

Tags: c

How would one convert a binary to a floating point? I don't see many implementations on this one (only floating point to binary).

So for example:

```
int main() {
    char example[32] = "-101.1101";
    float result = makeFloat(example);
    printf("Float number representation is: %f\n", result);
}

float makeFloat(char* f) {
     /* Empty */
}
```

Which the output would be:

```
-5.8125
```

Trying to get some practice in, but after hours of trying to figure it out, here I am asking for help.

Comment: Thanks for spending your effort, but you need to show the outcome till time.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please show your research effort till time. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: [strtod](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtod.htm) if you want a func. If you want to implement it, show your efforts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [character array to floating point conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15836866/character-array-to-floating-point-conversion)

Comment: Perhaps not that exact, but split at `.`; use `strtoll` on both sides; load right hand side to `double` and multiply by `0.5` `strlen(rhs)` times; then add/subtract the resulting fraction to left-hand side to get your number.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the website:

http://www.cprogramto.com/c-program-convert-binary-float/